# Using lightning:fileUpload component for uploading files without chatter Spring 18

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, files

I created a lightning component for uploading files due to the fact that in my business case, users are not meant to have access to chatter. So I opted for a component to do so, however when I try upload a file under a user without chatter access I get the following:

[image: Error Message]

I believe the issue might have to do with the Files object, but I see in Winter 16 there was talk of using files without chatter, I just dont know if in current release this still works. Is there a workaround to using files/attachments on lightning without enabling chatter?

I have looked at profile settings, is there perhaps an option Im meant to check for the user that is not chatter

Please advise

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem in my Lightning Community and according to the documentation,

> If your org uses profile-based Chatter rollout, users must have Chatter permissions enabled for Files to be available.
>   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_overview.htm&type=5

I would check your profile to see if you have profile based Chatter rollout - if you do, you'll see a checkbox called "Enable Chatter"